# Cargo test warns for unused code after saving file

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, rust-cargo

I'm starting to grasp Rust modules, but I have the following in a crate's `src` directory. If I make a small modification (add some whitespace or rename the test function), save and then immediately run `cargo test` I get a warning for an unused function, but if I wait a few seconds, and run it again, it runs with no warnings.

**lib.rs**

```
mod greet;

#[test]
pub fn it_greets_the_world_correctly() {
    assert_eq!("Hello, world!", greet::greet("world"));
}
```

**greet.rs**

```
pub fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello, {}!", name)
}
```

But when I run `cargo test` I get the following:

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling hello v0.1.0 (file:///F:/workspace/hello_rust)
src\greet.rs:1:1: 3:2 warning: function is never used: `greet`, #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
src\greet.rs:1 pub fn greet (name: &str) -> String {
src\greet.rs:2   format!("Hello, {}!", name)
src\greet.rs:3 }
     Running target\debug\hello-111b9369d8889475.exe

running 1 test
test it_greets_the_world_correctly ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

   Doc-tests hello

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

and then a few seconds later...

```
$ cargo test
     Running target\debug\hello-111b9369d8889475.exe

running 1 test
test it_greets_the_world_correctly ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

   Doc-tests hello

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

I'm not interested in suppressing the warning, I'm curious as to how Rust can possibly think the function is not being used when it's obviously called, since the test passes in both runs of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cargo test --verbose` will give you some answers.

Firstly `cargo test` will compile everything for the `lib` with `--crate-type lib`. This is what is causing your warning. `greet::greet` is not actually called in your library code.

Next, `cargo test` will run `rustc --crate-type lib --test` against the library as a separate step. This one *does* call `greet::greet`, and so you get no warning.

Now, if you touch the files again and change the test to this:

```
assert_eq!("Hello, world!", "Hello, world!");
```

You'll note you get two warnings of the same thing ... because both steps don't reference the `greet::greet` function (the library doesn't call it.. and the tests don't call it).

I think this is a valid warning and is what you want: The warning is saying you have a method that isn't called in your library code.. even if a test calls it. I think, in a larger codebase, you would want to be warned and clean up your tests that are now testing functions that aren't used in the main codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output closely:

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling hello v0.1.0 (file:///F:/workspace/hello_rust)
     Running target\debug\hello-111b9369d8889475.exe
```

```
$ cargo test
     Running target\debug\hello-111b9369d8889475.exe
```

When you execute `cargo test` the second time, nothing has changed with your code. Because nothing has changed, the code doesn't need to be recompiled.

Compiler warnings like unused functions are only generated when the compiler runs. If the compiler doesn't run, there won't be any warnings.

Changing the code will trigger a recompilation.

---

The followup question is, why does it think the function is unused? [Simon Whitehead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848976/155423) covers that. Even though the function is marked `pub`, the **module** it's in is not public. That means it's impossible to call the function outside of the library. Since there are no calls to it inside the library, it's unused.